# adding image/snapshot as a comment in Simulink Model

Tags: simulink

I made a Simulink model for a Polynomial curve and want to put the Polynomial equation in the model for the future reference. 
Is there a method I can add snapshot of that equation as a comment in the Simulink Model
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The best choice are [annotations](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/annotations.html). You might insert an image but I prefer the Equations option. It allows you to insert LaTex or MathML, which means the Euqtion an later be modified or resized without issues.